# Turning a string into an array and saving it as a new array, doesn't return original array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This function cleans up a string (removes all non-alphanumeric characters including underscores) then splits each letter into an array so that it can be reversed, then checked against the original.

At console.log(cleanStr) , it is returning the reversed array but I do not know why.

```
function checkIfPalindrome(str) {
  var cleanStr = str.toLowerCase().replace(replace, "" ).split("");
  var reversedStr = cleanStr.reverse();

  console.log(cleanStr); // why is this returning reverseStr, the reversed array? 

  if (cleanStr == reversedStr){
     return true
   }
  return false
}

checkIfPalindrome("five|\_/|four");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method reverses an array *in place* - it mutates the array it's called on. Try creating a new array instead:

```
const cleanStr = str.toLowerCase().replace(replace, "" ).split("");
const reversedStr = [...cleanStr].reverse();
```

Answer (score 1):

> At console.log(cleanStr) , it is returning the reversed array but I do not know why.

Because [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) reverses it **in place**.

Separately, you have a problem here:

```
if (cleanStr == reversedStr){
```

If they **were** different arrays, that would always be false, even if they had the same contents.

If you want to make a copy of the array and then reverse it, throw a `.slice()` in there:

```
var reversedStr = cleanStr.slice().reverse();
// -----------------------^
```

...and then compare after turning them back into strings:

```
if (cleanStr.join("") === reversedStr.join(""))
```

(I'd probably change those variable names, too, as they don't refer to strings.)

And finally, any time you find yourself writing:

```
if (x == b) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

back up and write

```
return x == b;
```

instead. :-)